# Pytube. Скачать несколько разные вариантов видео, определенный качеств и аудио

Tags: python, windows, youtube, download, pytube

Как в pytube cкачать аудио лучше качество из возможного и скачать отдельно видео с самым лучшим качеством, 480p. Всего должно получиться скаченных 3 файла

для примера вот видео:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldNTlFebTqE
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8gBfEDoEbY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться методами `filter` и `order_by`.

***Пример:***

```py
from pytube import YouTube


yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldNTlFebTqE')
streams = yt.streams

video_best = streams.order_by('resolution').desc().first()
video_480 = streams.filter(res='480p').desc().first()
audio_best = streams.filter(only_audio=True).desc().first()
```

Для скачивания вызовите метод [`download`](https://python-pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pytube.Stream.download). Советую сохранять под разными именами, чтобы случайно не перезаписать скачанный ранее `Stream`:

```py
video_best.download()
video_480_res.download()
audio_best.download()
```

---

**P. S.:**
Видео в максимальном разрешении часто не имеет аудиодорожки, поэтому Вам придётся вставлять её вручную, если это необходимо.

На примере `ffmpeg` (из консоли):

```
ffmpeg -i video.webm -i audio.webm -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy out.webm
```

**UPD:**
Лучшее видео (до 720p), имеющее аудиодорожку, можно получить так:

```py
video = streams.filter(progressive=True).desc().first()
```

Comment: Можно ли через python сразу как то это сделать? ffmpeg -i video.webm -i audio.webm -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy out.webm

Comment: @Юленька Конечно, например через [`os.system(command)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system). Но тут есть подводные камни, связанные с самим `ffmpeg`. Я не могу гарантировать правильную работу этой команды для всех форматов аудио и видео.

Comment: может тогда по другому, можно ли скачать видео с самым лучшим качеством, но чтобы было с аудио дорожкой? Конечно то видео что с самым лучшим качеством(пусть это видео и лучше чем то что выше описано), но без аудио дорожки проигнорирует

Comment: @Юленька Обновил ответ. За это отвечает параметр `progressive`. Кстати, у `ffmpeg` есть [обёртка](https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg-python/) для `Python`.